# Handling file not found

Tags: javascript, ajax, hyperlink

I have a link say [TestLink](http://testtesttesttest.co).

Clicking on which normally yields me a pdf.
Sometimes it diplays a page in a new window with message `file not found`

I need to respond when second case happens ,how do i handle this case via javascript?

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery

```
$.ajax( "http://link.to.pdf" )
 .fail(function() {
     // ... disable the link --> PDF is not reachable
 });
```

[source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

You can check the link, if the PDF is not reachable disable the link.

Comment: It doesn't seem very useful to tell the browser to download an entire PDF and then just show an alert instead of giving the user access to that PDF.